# Como le aplico una function a este array

Tags: php, array, wordpress, funciones

Tengo este array que me devuelve las `id` de las imagenes pero con una funcion de wordpress necesito aplicarselas a cada una de las `id` que devuelva el `array` y esta funcion se encargara de convertirlas en url, cada una.

Esto devuelve el array con un `var_dump()`.

```
array(2) {\n  [0]=>\n  int(10741)\n  [1]=>\n  int(10742)\n}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Muriano ya te dió una respuesta, para obtener todas los id de las imágenes, debes almacenarlas en un array.

```
<?php
    foreach($arrayImagenes as $idImagen) {
        $urlImagen[] = funcion_wordpress($idImagen);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    foreach($arrayImagenes as $idImagen) {

          $urlImagen = funcion_wordpress($idImagen);

    }
```

A partir de ese código ya decides si quieres guardar cada url de imagen en una variable o en un array. `foreach` es una estructura que funciona con elementos de tipo "iterable" y te permite almacenar en una variable (as $idImage) cada una de estas "iteraciones" para trabajar con ellas de la forma en que desees, por ejemplo, pasarlo como argumento a una función.

Comment: Funciona pero no del todo @Muriano, lo que ocurre es que solo me muestra el enlace de la ultima imagen.

Comment: @SantiagoD'Antuoni Se trataba de un código guía para que tú desarrollaras la solución final. Ya te han dado la solución completa, bastaba con almacenar cada salida de la función en un array.